# Erro ao tentar atribuir um novo valor de um objeto de repetição

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso atribuir ou mesmo criar um novo atributo em um objeto dentro de um laço, porém está dando o seguinte erro, que não faço ideia do que seja:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'is_content_hide' on boolean 'false'

```
EmailService.setMail(data)
     .then(function(result){
         if (result.status) {
            if (angular.isDefined(result.em_massa) && result.em_massa) {
                for (var i in $scope.content.dados) {
                    if ($scope.content.dados[i]) {
                       $scope.content.dados[j].is_content_hide = true;
                    }
                }
            }
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta comparando se existe o `if ($scope.content.dados[i])` utilizando a variavel `i` mas atribui o valor utilizando a variavel `j`